# Do Jews have to keep the 7 Noahide laws?

Tags: mitzvah, noachide-laws

Well, I heard that a Jew only has to keep a Noahide law if it's repeated in the Torah, since Jews aren't obligated in Noahide laws. The practical application of this would be an exemption from the law of eiver min hachai (eating from a live animal). Is this true?

- Since the Malbim says by the machloket of Yosef and his brothers were whether they were noahides or jews. Yosef held they were noahides and therefore if animal is shected if its moving its eiver min hachai.

Comment: See http://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%A4%D7%A8%D7%A9%D7%AA_%D7%93%D7%A8%D7%9B%D7%99%D7%9D_%D7%93%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%A9_%D7%90

Comment: I think what you mean to ask is if there could be a practical difference between "ever min hachai" for a Jew vs. a gentile. It is [definitely forbidden](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/27900/1535) for Jews too, however for Jews schitah is enough, but not for a gentile. If this is your question, please edit it to be more clear.

Comment: you awnsered it with shceeta is enough for jews and not for gentiles.

Comment: This question is the opposite of true. The Gemara says that laws are only binding on Noahides if they are repeated, but if they are not repeated they are only binding on Jews. See Sanhenrin 59a: מצוה שנאמרה ולא נשנית, לישראל נאמרה ולא לבני נח

Comment: doesnt it say somme of noahide commandments in the 10 commandments?

Answer (score 4):

Eiver min hachai is repeated in the Torah and forbidden to Jews, (see [Sefer Hachinuch here](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=40631&st=&pgnum=585&hilite=)).

See also [Ever Min Hachai - A Limb from a Living Animal](http://www.targum.com/excerpts/major_concepts.html).

Answer (score 3):

Yes, but not because the Mitzvos Bnei Noach apply to Jews.

The Sheva Mitzvos are not to (1) eat a limb from live animal, (2) commit idolatry, (3) murder, (4) commit adultery, (5) steal, (6) have a city without a court system, or (7) "bless" (curse) Hashem.

(1) Eating a limb from a live animal is prohibited by the Mitzvah of Shechitah. (2-4) Idolatry, murder, and adultery are prohibited in the Aseres HaDibros. (5) Stealing isn't, because that "stealing" is actually a reference to kidnaping (source: somewhere in Sanhedrin). The prohibition against stealing is actually in Kedoshim. (6) Court systems became obligatory in Parshas Shoftim. (7) "Blessing" Hashem became prohibited in Parshas Emor.